# Unable to access Superclass's public member variable from Subclass

Tags: apex, inheritance

I am trying assign value into the Super class member variable which is declared as `public`, but unable to access that SuperClass variable from Subclass.

> It is throwing compiler error, **Variable does not exist: super.recordId**

**SuperClass**

```
public virtual class EmployeeSuperClass
{
    public Id recordId {get;set;}
    
    public virtual PageReference displayEmployee()
    {
        //query to retrieve employee data based on recordId
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Subclass**

```
public class EmployeeCustomController extends EmployeeSuperClass{
    private Id recordId {get;set;}
    public EmployeeCustomController()
    {
        recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    }

    public override PageReference displayEmployee(){
        super.recordId = this.recordId;   //giving error ---> Variable does not exist: super.recordId 
        return super.displayEmployee();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something. The `Apex Developer Guide` lays it out succinctly (emphasis mine):

> ## [Using the `super` Keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_super.htm)
>
> The `super` keyword can be used by classes that are extended from virtual or abstract classes. By using `super`, you can override **constructors and methods** from the parent class.

When you set `recordId = someVariable` you *are* setting it at the `SuperClass` level. Paste this simple analogous script in `Execute Anonymous` to demonstrate how extending a class works when manipulating member variables and methods (note that classes are virtual by default in that environment):

```
class SuperClass
{
    String bar;
    public void foo() { system.debug(bar); }
}
class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    SubClass() { bar = 'Hello World!'; }
}

new SubClass().foo();
```

So in your implementation, you can actually drop the override entirely. For example, you could implement it as follows:

```
public virtual class EmployeeSuperClass
{
    Id recordId;
    public PageReference view() {
        return new ApexPages.StandardController(new Employee__c(Id=recordId)).view();
    }
}
public class EmployeeSubClass
{
    public EmployeeSubClass()
    {
        recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but perhaps you could just say "super is only used to call the super-class' constructor?"

Comment: So, Super is only used to call constructor and methods? not for variables, correct?

Comment: Actually, this is as opposed to Java, where super class member variables can be accessed as 'super.variableName', refer http://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/super-keyword-in-java-with-example/